# Array of numbers inside a JTextField - Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield

I'm trying to make a JTextField receive an array of numbers. I tryed with "for" and all the stuff needed to run an array, but without succes. Here is the piece  of code.

```
private void cbxGeraValorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{        
    if(cbxRandom.isSelected())
    {
        double[] num = new double[10];

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            num[i] = r.rnd;
            txtValor.setText(String.valueOf(num[i]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your example you are replacing the text with a random number 10 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(cbxRandom.isSelected())
{
    double[] num = new double[10];
    String newtxt = "";
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        num[i] = r.rnd;
        newtxt += String.valueOf(num[i]);
    }
    txtValor.setText(newtxt); //do setting only after the loop ends
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(cbxRandom.isSelected())
{
    double[] num = new double[10];
    String newtxt = "";
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        num[i] = r.rnd;
        newtxt += String.valueOf(num[i]) + " "; // Separate numbers
    }
    txtValor.setText(newtxt); //do setting only after the loop ends
}
```